# How can I show a modal backdrop with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to show modal window backdrop programatically by calling in javascript, but I can't find the way to do it.

I thougth it is set by adding `modal-open` css class to the body, but it is not the case.

How can I show up the backdrop only?

Thank you

Comment: It all depends on what you have already. Can you edit your question to show us some code HTML/CSS/JS? I've previously done this by having two DIVs, and some CSS. One of the DIVs starts off missing a class, which I add using JS, then it appears. Also are you using JQuery or any other JS framework?

Comment: Yes, I'm rewriting it to React

Comment: [React and Bootstrap play nicely together](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/). Be sure that you're not reinventing wheels.

Comment: As far as I know you should not manipulate with DOM directly when using React, right?

Comment: Correct. You'd create a "dumb" mask component and toggle visibility with property values.

Comment: But masks are built into React-Bootstrap components. You shouldn't have to do that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`.modal('toggle')` manually toggles a modal. Returns to the caller before the modal has actually been shown or hidden (i.e. before the `shown.bs.modal` or `hidden.bs.modal` event occurs).

```
$('#myModal').modal('toggle')
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

I hope this helps

Comment: I’m not using jquery, I’m trying to set it up just by vanilla javascript (rewriting to React)

Comment: "*Many of our components require the use of JavaScript to function. Specifically, they require jQuery*" Bootstrap **requires** jQuery. How/why are you not using it?

Comment: I’m rewriting it to React. jQuery with modal is not doing anything else than adding/removing css classes. So am I in React. Just can’t find out what class on what element I’m missing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so for others - if you want to show a backdrop, you must append a div `<div class="modal-backdrop fade show" />` to DOM when the modal is open.

Comment: This doesn't sound like good practice. You shouldn't need to do such things manually. You might revise your question as DJDaveMark suggested to get a better solution.